# Access the content of a nested Iframe

Tags: iframe, nested

I am creating an applicaiton where I want to access the content of nestend iframe.
Say I have a page test.aspx
Now there is an iframe say iframe1. and the content of this iframe is another iframe. say iframe2
So its a nested iframe.
Now I want to access the content of the iframe2.
How we can access the content of this 2nd iframe as I have to search some text in the 2nd iframe.
I want to access the iframe with javascript or jquery only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow;
```

and for the innerHTML use

frameElement.contentDocument.activeElement

```
var iframeFound = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow;
         var   ifrme = iframeFound.frameElement.contentDocument.activeElement;
```